# Which is the Best way for SQL server (2008) synchronization over internet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I have two identical SQL server databases. One is the main database and the other is a remote database, which is in a remote location. Both the computers are connected using VPN. Some tables in the remote database has to be updated every 10 minutes.

Is database synchronization a better option? Do we have to develop the software using C# or other programming language? Do we have to use WCF?

Comment: Have you tried SQL Replication?

Comment: Microsoft sync framework might be helpful.

Comment: Check out SQL Server replication http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx

Comment: Without knowing more, it's hard to say. I'd suggest looking at [Log Shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx) though.

Comment: As of SQL Server 2012, there are no synchronous replication options.  Bidirectional replication is not synchronous...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Also, what do you need the remote data for?  Reporting?  Lastly, do you just need a subset of tables?  There are several technologies that could work here, depending on the strengths in your development and support teams.

Comment: @Strommy : I am using sql server 2008. I have a wpf application where the server resides in one place and the clients are in remote locations over the internet. The clients use an exact copy of the main database and it is being updated at regular intervels. I am using a subset of tables to update